# isNaN function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nan

why is isNaN function in nodejs returning **false** in the following cases?

```
isNaN(''),isNaN('\n'),isNaN('\t')
```

this is very weird.

does somebody have any ideas as I thought isNaN stood for is Not a Number.

can someone please clarify

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you are not passing it a number, it will convert it to number. All of those convert to `0` which is `0` and not `NaN`

```
Number('')
0
Number('\n')
0
Number('\t')
0
isNaN(0)
false
```

Note that `NaN` does not stand for "not a JavaScript Number". [In fact it's completely separate from JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and exists in all languages that support IEEE-754 floats.

If you want to check if something is a javascript number, the check is

```
if (typeof value === "number") {

}
```

Comment: Note that the value `NaN` is a Javascript Number => `typeof NaN === 'number' // true`

Answer (score 5):

`isNan()` is designed to help detect things that are 'mathematically undefined' - e.g. `0/0` -

```
node
> isNaN(0/0)
true
> isNaN(1/0)
false
> isNaN(Math.sqrt(-1))
true
> isNaN(Math.log(-1))
true
```

The other advice you got here in this question on how to detect numbers is solid.

Answer (score 4):

NaN is a very specific thing: it is a floating point value which has the appropriate NaN flags set, per the IEEE754 spec ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008)).

If you want to check whether a string has a numeric value in it, you can do `parseFloat(str)` ([MDN on parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)). If that fails to find any valid numeric content, or finds invalid characters before finding numbers, it will return a NaN value.

So try doing `isNaN(parseFloat(str))` - it gives me `true` for all three examples posted.

Comment: yup this is what I am using but it would have been simpler if isNaN would have done the trick...

Comment: @A-0-: isNaN has a specific purpose; to detect NaN values according to the IEEE754 spec. It is not there to be a general numeric check, that is mostly being done in parseFloat whose job is to construct numbers from strings. We are only employing isNaN here because parseFloat returns a NaN value when it fails; if it had thrown an error, we wouldn't be using isNaN. Do not confuse isNaN with a kind of isNumeric - isNaN only operates on numeric values, not strings, and checks for a specific type of value.

Answer (score 0):

isNaN is a "is Not a Number" function, it returns true when no number are give to it as parameter, and false when a number is given

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant to say "false" when a number is given. You may want to edit your answer to correct it.